# convert raster (GeoTiff) to ascii with no numbers after decimal

Tags: r, decimal, ascii, raster

I have a raster file (GeoTiff). I converted it to ASCII in R. After the conversion, a lot of numbers are coming after the decimal point. I want to make an ASCII with only integer values.

```
writeRaster(a, sigdig = 0, filename = "K:/ouput/test.asc")
```

[screenshot of my ascii](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh9Pc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `round()` on the vectors you want rounded?

Comment: I tried this and it worked except the first number comes as 1042.000000000000000. Instead I want it as only 1042.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
writeRaster(round(a), filename = "K:/ouput/test.asc")
```

Let's try with some example data

```
library(raster)
a <- raster(ncol=2, nrow=2, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1)
values(a) <- 1:4 * pi
```

Now write and read the file

```
writeRaster(a, filename = "test.asc")
readLines("test.asc")
#[1] "NCOLS 2 "                           "NROWS 2 "                          
#[3] "XLLCORNER 0 "                       "YLLCORNER 0 "                      
#[5] "CELLSIZE 0.5 "                      "NODATA_value -9999 "               
#[7] "3.141592653589790 6.28318530717959" "9.42477796076938 12.5663706143592"
```

First round, then write and read

```
ra <- round(a)
writeRaster(ra, filename = "test2.asc")
readLines("test2.asc")
#[1] "NCOLS 2 "            "NROWS 2 "            "XLLCORNER 0 "       
#[4] "YLLCORNER 0 "        "CELLSIZE 0.5 "       "NODATA_value -9999 "
#[7] "3.000000000000000 6" "9 13"
```

The first value still has decimals (a trick to avoid that real values get truncated) but the others do not.

Comment: How will get rid of this first value problem?